# How can I pause the onDraw function without disabling the other views?

Tags: android, textview, sleep, ondraw, settext

My code changes the text of a `textView` periodically. The text must be displayed on the screen for an exact amount of milliseconds. To do this, I check the last time the `onDraw` function was called and I pause the execution (with `parkNanos` function) until the desired next redraw. But doing this, all the other views of the display were disabled. I've tried `postDelayed` but it isn't enough accurate because there is a lapse of milliseconds between the `setText` calling and the `onDraw` calling.

How can I solve this problem?

I hope I've explained that clearly.

Thank you.

Comment: "But doing this, all the other views of the display were disabled" -- you froze the main application thread with `parkNanos()`. Hence, you froze the UI. "I've tried postDelayed but it isn't enough accurate because there is a lapse of milliseconds between the setText calling and the onDraw calling" -- correct.

Comment: Thank you. I will use a SurfaceView.